# How to use webkit-mask-box-image with a Retina-quality image?

Tags: css, webkit, media-queries, retina-display, masking

Is it possible to achieve Retina-quality CSS masking using `-webkit-mask-box-image`? In this particular case, I am trying to round the corners of an element (`border-radius` is not performant enough):

```
.element {
    -webkit-mask-box-image: url('mask.png') 12 12 12 12 stretch stretch;
}
```

The mask image is twice the size that it needs to be (`6` is used in place of `12` for non-retina screens).

The mask is correctly positioned, but the corner rounding is not Retina-smooth.

Comment: I would say that scaling bitmaps is waaay more performance heavy than border-radius. Proved by actual tests.

Comment: Initial tests (just eyeballing it) indicate that `-webkit-mask-box-image` allows for smoother scrolling than `border-radius` does.

Answer (score 1):

I see three solutions, here:

- Suck it up and deal with border-radius, because you can't be getting *that* much lag on modern machines. Plus, only Safari and Chrome (and minor webkit-based browsers like RockMelt,
  Yandex, et cetera) use `-webkit-mask`, so unless you're making a Chrome app, you're losing a lot of your audience (currently about 54.25%) to browser incompatibility, not to mention that it requires the user to download an image just to see rounded corners.
- Webkit uses image smoothing within its scaling algorithm, so simply provide a gigantic mask image and let it do its one-time scaling on load. This has the inherent downside of taking much longer to download and some time after to scale, but, again, it's a one-time thing until the cache clears.
- Instead of using a PNG, use an SVG. The whole point of **S**‍calable **V**‍ector **G**‍raphics is that they're infinitely scalable and don't lose quality at any resolution or size. For more on how to make a SVG file, see http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/